# MySQL select query containing alpha characters

Tags: mysql

I need a MySQL query that searches a field that contains letters (can contain other characters as well, but I want ones that also contain letters).

This returns nothing:

```
SELECT phone 
  FROM members 
 WHERE phone REGEXP '^[[:alpha:]]+$'
```

Comment: To be more precise, your regexp says "**only** letters, from start to end". Is that the problem? You need to specify in more detail, what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That regex will return values that are comprised *only* of letters, as it looks for a sequence of 1 or more alphabetic characters between the start and end of the string, which precludes any non-alphabetic character. If you just want fields that contain 1 or more letters, just use

```
select phone from members where phone REGEXP '[[:alpha:]]'
```